# 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblPurchase'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblPurchase'. The duplicate key value is ()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I have this code where you can import Excel data into SQL Server. I'm using C# as a way to import the Excel data into SQL Server.

I'm encountering an error on the last line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the error I get:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblPurchase'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblPurchase'. The duplicate key value is ()

This is my code:

```
public partial class FrmPurchase : Form
{
    public FrmPurchase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = tableCollection[cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    DataTableCollection tableCollection;

    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" })
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFilename.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;

                using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                    {
                        DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
                        tableCollection = result.Tables;
                        cboSheet.Items.Clear();

                        foreach (DataTable table in tableCollection)
                            cboSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName); //add sheet to combobox
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = @"Data Source=LEGION-MC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            con.Open();

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string itemCode = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                string itemCost = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                string itemSRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                string itemQty = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                string supplierID = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                string categoryID = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                string itemStatus = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                string datePurchased = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblPurchase (Item_Code, Item_Cost, Item_SRP, Item_QTY, Supplier_ID, Category_ID, Item_Status, Date_Purchased) VALUES (@ItemCode, @ItemCost, @ItemSRP, @ItemQty, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @ItemStatus, @DatePurchased)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", itemCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCost", itemCost);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemSRP", itemSRP);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemQty", itemQty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", supplierID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", categoryID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemStatus", itemStatus);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePurchased", datePurchased);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem here is I get the error but still the data coming from Excel is imported into my SQL Server with the same value but there's always this error.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is telling you there is a primary key constraint violation - which means an attempt was made to insert a primary key value which already exists.  I am assuming **ItemCode** is your primary key?   The error message also shows the value is empty or null.  So, perhaps a check like the following might help:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string itemCode = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

            if ( !System.String.IsNullOrEmpty( itemCode ) ) {

               string itemCost = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
               string itemSRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
               string itemQty = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
               string supplierID = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
               string categoryID = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
               string itemStatus = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
               string datePurchased = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);


               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblPurchase (Item_Code, Item_Cost, Item_SRP, Item_QTY, Supplier_ID, Category_ID, Item_Status, Date_Purchased) VALUES (@ItemCode, @ItemCost, @ItemSRP, @ItemQty, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @ItemStatus, @DatePurchased)", con))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", itemCode);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCost", itemCost);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemSRP", itemSRP);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemQty", itemQty);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", supplierID);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", categoryID);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemStatus", itemStatus);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePurchased", datePurchased);


                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
            }
        }
```

Also, should the **for** loop (as shown above) start at 0 rather than 1 as the dataGridView1 Rows property are probably indexed starting at zero?

Hope that helps.

Comment: We use 1 in the for loop as a start because of the header of the Excel. Thank you for this!

Comment: Ah, in that case it makes sense.   You may want to include an additional check then to make sure at least one Row exists before entering the loop otherwise an exception will be thrown.